# How to change the block size in Hyper Ledger Fabric 2.X?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to adjust the size of newly created blocks. I found that there is `AbsoluteMaxBytes` in `configtx.yaml`. However, I do not understand how to change it. I have docker images including peer and orderer. Both peer and orderer I suppose have default values including default value for `AbsoluteMaxBytes`. Should I rebuild docker images after I change `configtx.yaml` or should I somehow modify `AbsoluteMaxBytes` inside running container?

What is the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

This requires a channel config update to be done.
Please refer here:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html?highlight=channel%20config%20update

Comment: It's a valid, but I have docker based peers, orderers, etc. What to do in that case?

Comment: How you have deployed your fabric network isn't an issue, the process for updating a channel configuration is the same regardless of whether docker/K8s/Native deployment is done so this tutorial is relevant for a docker based deployment. But I will agree it's not trivial and it will require a lot of investigation on your part to work out how to modify the fetched config block, create the delta, build and appropriately sign the channel config update and submit it.